# Django rest framework serializer exclude not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

so I have the following two serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ("password",)

class FooBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = FooBar
        fields = ("user",)
```

When I run my view to get the `FooBar` info, it still displays the users password...**why?**

## the view

```
class FooBar(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    queryset = FooBar.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooBarSerializer
```

Comment: Are you sure `UserSerializer` is really used in your `FooBarSerializer` ?

Comment: @BenjaminToueg what do you mean by that? I mean I need it to be used in it, and doesn't my code ensure that?